# javascript replace character with space

Tags: javascript

I am tryingto replace `*` for a space. I got a loop of information like this : "FC Girondins de Bordeaux*null*null*OSC Lille" I would like to change the `*` for a simple space. I tried to split the information but that didn't work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: @cale_b I could, but replacing text in a string is JS 101. If OP doesn't understand that, they should read the entire article I posted.

Comment: "That didn't work".  Why not? What "didn't work" about it? Be specific.  In programming, a single out-of-place `.` character will break everything, so the details matter.

Comment: @Ronnie - excellent point.  This is a duplicate, the OP simply hasn't properly identified the problem clearly.  Ah, the challenge of keeping SO clean and useful....

Comment: @cale_b I agree, nor is it related to angular or local storage.

Comment: Yep. I've voted to close....

Answer (score 1):

```
var newString = str.split("*").join(" ");
```

Explanation : .split splits the string into an array using '*' as a delimiter, then using .join it takes that array and effectively unsplits it back into a string using a space as delimiter.

For the null exception there's a bunch of ways to handle it.  Either you can be explicit in testing the typeof the value or whether it is null or use a try, catch statement to handle all errors.

```
var newString;
  try {
   newString = str.split("*").join(" ");
} catch(err){
  newString = ""; //or whatever you want to do with the string when it's null
}
```

Comment: Yeah, while this will work, how does it work? Can you link to the documentation? Code-only answers are not very useful, as they don't explain what you're doing.

Comment: i tried my code look like that : 
for ( var i = 1, len = localStorage.length+1; i < len; ++i ) {
     localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) ).split("*").join(" ");
  };

and i got this : 
Cannot read property 'split' of null

Comment: @Twinny - that error describes the problem: In some instances, the value you're trying to work with is *null*, which will not allow split.  Defensively program to prevent *null* from attempting to split.

Comment: This solution **does not protect** against instances where this will throw an error.  How would you do that? Using the native js function like you have, it's fairly brittle.  That's one of the reasons I enjoy using a library such as [lodash](https://lodash.com/) - it's [split](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#split) function doesn't puke when there's a problem.